# WPF User Control Item Control Binding Issue

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I am creating a user control in WPF which is a type of Item control. This control will have two columns one will display the check box and another will display the description corresponding to the check box. When this control is deployed to a WPF form, it will bind with a collection. Based on the collection items the number of check box will display in item control and another column of item control will bind with some property of collection.

Now the problem here is, how can I define the binding on user control for the check box description column? On user control we are not aware of the property of collection, it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model class, an helper class to represent your data. Create for example a class with two property:

```
class CheckModel
{
   public bool Checked {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Let CheckModel implemets `INotifyPropertyChanged` if your data changes dynamically and you have to show this changes in the UI.

then create in the main model a `ObservableCollection<CheckModel>` and bind your user control to it. Use some strategy to map your underlaying real data in `CheckModel` instances.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create DependencyProperty in your user control which will be used to bind check box and description. Some Thing Like this

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {


        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsChecked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));



        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }     

    }
```

And your usercontrol xaml looks like following..

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Name="Root">

    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=Root}"></CheckBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=Root}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

If you observe i have binded check box and textbox to the dependency properties i have created in user control.

when you use the usercontrol you can bind the DependencyProperty

```
<Grid>
                <local:UserControl1 IsChecked="{Binding yourBinding}" Text="{Binding yourBinding}"/>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

My CheckBoxList user control looks like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="CheckBoxListControl.CheckBoxListControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="CheckedListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="templateCheckBox" Content="{Binding CheckBoxDisplayColumn}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

On this user control ItemsSource and CheckBoxDisplayColumn are DP's, which i want to set from my client app as below

```
<userControl35:CheckBoxListControl Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" 
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding personObservableCollection}"
                                       CheckBoxDisplayColumn="EmployeeName"></userControl35:CheckBoxListControl>
```

personObservableCollection is of type Employee having properties EmployeeName, Age, Gender

I want a way by which "EmployeeName" provided to DP CheckBoxDisplayColumn on client app becomes the property which my CheckBoxList control uses to Display checkboxes as against Gender or Age

Basically, i would like to make the control generic so that a user consuming it can specify the Collection to Bind to and the Display Column to which to bind to from the collection